# Checking password match, unexpected operation. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, css, passwords, css-transitions, addeventlistener

I have written this function which show a message with animation when no match passwords. This works half well, the problem is when I write something in the first pasword input and then write one letter on the second password input, the message suddenly disappears breaking the animation, then if I write more letters the message reappears. I don't know what I am doing wrong, may be the function is not properly made and could be done differently. I was very grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
const password = document.querySelector("#password"),
  password2 = document.querySelector("#password2");

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {

  password.addEventListener('input', matchPassword);
  password2.addEventListener('input', matchPassword);
}

function matchPassword() {
  const inputPassword = document.querySelector("#password"),
    inputPassword2 = document.querySelector("#password2"),
    error = document.querySelector(".password2 .error");
  if (inputPassword2.value === "") {
    error.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      error.innerHTML = '';
    }, {
      once: true
    });
    error.classList.remove("show");
  } else if (inputPassword.value !== inputPassword2.value) {
    error.innerHTML = `<p>no match passwords</p>`;
    error.classList.add("show");
  } else if(inputPassword.value === inputPassword2.value){
    error.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      error.innerHTML = '';
    }, {
      once: true
    });
    error.classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password2">
  <label for="password2">Password:</label>
  <i class="fas fa-lock icono-input"></i>
  <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repeat password">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're listening to `input` event which is triggered every time a key is pressed. Listen to `change` event instead